# Как и когда впервые возникло неправильное написание выражения "в общем": "вообщем"?

Tags: вводные-слова, слитно-раздельно, типы-ошибок

В последнее время всё чаще допускают ошибку в выражении "в общем": пишут "вообщем". Есть вопрос, как и когда возникло такое неправильное написание данного выражения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравним два совершенно разных по смыслу предложения:

```
Мне вообще все равно = Мне совсем все равно.
Мне, в общем, все равно = Мне, вообще говоря, все равно.
```

Таким образом логических предпосылок связывать **вообще** и **в общем** как будто бы нет. Хотя **в общем** в редких случаях употребляется в качестве наречия и в точности эквивалентно вообще. Но эти случаи редки:

```
В общем говоря, мне все равно.
Вообще говоря, мне все равно.
```

Теперь можно вернуться к исходному вопросу. Когда и как возникло сие порождение собаки с ежом? Да по пьяни какой-то шутник придумал. Логики никакой.